# jquery Click event doesn't fires

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick

I'm not sure my `closeContent();`doesn't fire. I trying to load something and then close it and animate stuff with css3.

also I'd like to show the loader but not sure its the best approach.

```
    $('.show-content').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        openContent();
    });

    $('#load-content .prev').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        closeContent();
    });


    function openContent(){

    $('#load-content').load('../views/product-page.html');

    $('.container').addClass('loaded', function () {
         //setTimeout(function () {
                $('#load-content').html('<img id="loader" src="../assets/images/bx_loader.gif">');
            $('#loader').css({border: '0', position: 'absolute', top: '26px', left: '50%', 'margin-left': '-26px'});
                console.log('loading???')
        //}, 60000);
    });

    $("#load-content").bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function () {
        $(this).addClass('animate');
        var body = $("body,html");

                body.animate({
                  scrollTop: 0
                }, 800);
    });
    }

    function closeContent(){
        var Loaded = !$(this).closest('.container').hasClass('.loaded');
        if (!Loaded) {
                $('.animate').removeClass('animate');
            $("#load-content").bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function () {
          $('.loaded').removeClass('loaded');
          $('#show-content').remove();
          });
        }           
    }
```

Comment: Make sure all these calls are happening inside the onload function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `this`

```
$('#load-content .prev').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    closeContent(this);
});
```

then in the function

```
function closeContent(ele){
     var Loaded = !$(ele).closest('.container').hasClass('.loaded');
```

if `.prev` element is dynamically added use event delegation.

```
$('#load-content').on('click','.prev',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    closeContent(this);
});
```

or

```
$(document).on('click','#load-content .prev',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    closeContent(this);
});
```

Comment: thanks but dunno why but the click still doesn't fires

Comment: @user1161108 Is .prev element dynamically added?

Comment: thanks now $(document).on('click','#load-content .prev',function (e){
       e.preventDefault();
       closeContent(this);
       console.log('click');
   }); like this I can see the console.log but doesn't trigger the rest of the function, dunno why???

Comment: Change `.hasClass('.loaded')` to `.hasClass('loaded')` remove the **`.`**

Comment: thanks good spotted. I'm not sure why  openContent(); kicks in every time animation ends!!!! what  Am I missing?